# How can I remove members of a list of strings of equal length, based on the presence of specific characters in certain positions of the strings?

Tags: python

I'm sorry if I don't explain this well, but here it goes: 
I have a list of strings such as this, all of them of the same length:

```
list_strings=["abc-df-r-e","abc--daa-q","-ab-c-aub-","cbac-a-c--"]
```

And I have a list of integers which are positions of the strings in the previous list (so the positions are all from 0 to 9, since the length of every string is 10):

```
list_positions=[2,0,4,7]
```

What I'm trying to do is, for each position in the second list, remove from the first list, the strings that don't have either "a", "b", "c" or "-" in those positions.

In this case the first string would be removed because it has a "d" in position 4, and the third string would be removed because it has a "u" in position 7.
So the output in this case would be:

```
list_strings=["abc--daa-q","cbac-a-c--"]
```

I tried this but I don't know if it's the best approach:

```
list_approved=["a","b","c","-"]
for i in list_strings:
     for j,k in enumerate(i):
          if j in list_positions:
               if i[j] not in list_approved:
                    list_strings.remove(i)
               else:
                    pass
```

Thanks in advance for any answer

Comment: Your code doesnt work for me. Once you removed 'i' you should use a break to go to the next iteration of the inner loop

Comment: String `"cbdc-a-c--"` will be removed too: there's `d` in position `2`, no?

Comment: should I had the break right below the "list_strings.remove(i)"?

Comment: yes you're right I'll correct it

Comment: You might want to iterate over the list_positions in the outermost loop because the inner loops might try to  remove a list item multiple times if the outermost loop is over `list_strings`.

Comment: Why do I bother to explain stuff and give advice in my answers when the accepted ones are the code-only ones ^^ :(

Comment: I'm sorry, it was just because they posted earlier, in these cases I never know what to do : ( usually I go by the first person who solved it, you answer and explanation were very useful as well, thank you a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A solution with list-comprehension:

```
list_strings=["abc-df-r-e","abc--daa-q","-ab-c-aub-","cbac-a-c--"]
list_positions=[2,0,4,7]

list_strings = [s for s in list_strings if not any(ch not in 'abc-' and i in list_positions for i, ch in enumerate(s))]
print(list_strings)
```

Prints:

```
['abc--daa-q', 'cbac-a-c--']
```

---

EDIT: Thanks to @David Wierichs, a faster solution:

```
list_strings = [s for s in list_strings if not any(s[i] not in 'abc-' for i in list_positions)]
```

Comment: Just out of curiousity: Would it be faster to do `any(s[i] not in 'abc-' for i in list_positions)` as one does not have to iterate through the entire strings in list_strings?

Comment: @DavidWierichs yep, that's faster (and clever :). I'll edit my answer!

Answer (score 2):

A good pythonic way is to use the "filter" function which can filter out from a list with a specific, user-defined, filter. In order to do so you will need the function to know the list_approved so it could filter out accordingly,

to do so you can use a wrapper or a "partial" function. For simplistic reasons we will use partial from functools. This function allows to send the function arguments in different times, for more information check out:

https://docs.python.org/2/library/functools.html#functools.partial

This code does filter out according to your rules

```
from functools import partial
list_strings=["abc-df-r-e","abc--daa-q","-ab-c-aub-","cbac-a-c--"]
list_positions=[2,0,4,7]
list_approved=["a","b","c","-"]


def filter_out_according_to_position(list_positions, list_approved, currnet_string):
    return all([currnet_string[i] in list_approved for i in list_positions])


new_list = list(filter(partial(filter_out_according_to_position, list_positions, list_approved), list_strings))

print(new_list)
```

Hope that helped

Answer (score 1):

You may not remove element while iterating on a the list itself, because that break the indexing and you do not check every element at the end. With you code, `"cbdc-a-c--"` is not tested for example.

- use meaningfull names
- use the variable `letter` directly, instead of `word[idx_letter]`
- combine the 2 ifs
- use a `break` to stop the inner loop when reaching a forbidden letter

Iterate on `list(list_strings)`, this make a copy if the list, and you can then remove from `list_strings` without problem

```
for word in list(list_strings):
    for idx_letter, letter in enumerate(word):
        if idx_letter in list_positions and letter not in list_approved:
            list_strings.remove(word)
            break
print(list_strings)
```

The other to see it is : keep the word that matches, using a list comprehension

```
list_strings = [word for word in list_strings
                if not any(letter not in list_approved and i in list_positions for i, letter in enumerate(word))]
```